# Cron jobs for Sitemaps in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sitemaps

I have to setup cron jobs for Sitemaps in Magento 2 on daily basis.

How will I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't achieve this due to Magento bug [#5760](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5768). You may need an additional extension.